# Delete chains from a protein

Tags: protein-structure

We have a docking target protein with multiple chains (A,B and C). However, I just need chain A. How can I delete the 2 other chains from the docking target protein.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi @ibio_rep1, sorry to be persistent but please remember to accept one of the answers below. I didn't know about the pdb tools and its useful trick to know. It is important for the momentum of the site. Both respondees are serious structural bioinformaticians.

Answer (score 2):

If the tag `r` is incorrect, the easiest way is to download and install `PyMOL`: https://pymol.org/2/

Drap and drop your pdb file and type `remove not chain A`.
Then save molecule via the menu as pdb or type `save some_file_name.pdb` (will be in your home root folder).

Comment: Thank you for the help. Appreciate it.

Comment: Hi @ibio_rep1 could you please upvote the answer (ok once yuo have sufficient rep) and if you feel it resolves your question mark it as 'accepted'. This is super important because otherwise it discourages answering new OPs.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this with [pdb-tools](http://www.bonvinlab.org/pdb-tools/):

```
pdb_selchain -A prot.pdb > prot_A.pdb
```